# how can one use 'embedded-glassfish:admin' to create a datasource

Tags: maven, glassfish, glassfish-embedded

There a many articals pointing to embedded-glassfish:admin when it comes to create a datasource for embedded glassfish. But at the end there is now good description of how this should actually work.

- http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/nonav/plugindocs/3.1/admin-mojo.html
- http://blogs.oracle.com/sirajg/entry/using_maven_plugin_for_v3

has anyone successfully used the 'embedded-glassfish:admin' goal to create a datasource for e.g. H2 or Oracle? And if so, how do you deal with the driver if you don't have the driver jar packaged in your WAR?